# schreier problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ of finite index, where $G$ is finitely generated. Show that $H$ is finitely generated. In fact, if $T$ is a right transversal for $H$ in $G$ and $X$ is agenerating set for $G$, define
$$Y=\{tx(t.x)^{-1}: t\in T,x \in X\}$$ and show that Y generates H.
Hint: Let $K=\left< Y \right>$ and show that $\{Kt : t \in T\}$ is the full set of right cosets of $K$ in $G$.Do this by proving that these cosets are permuted among themselves by right multiplication by elements of $G$.
It is problem 9.11 from M.Isaacs Algebra. I really do not know how to establish this; even i dont know what the hint will eventuate.
I would be thankful for your helps and advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a summary of how to do it.

1. It is sufficient to show that, for each $g \in G$, $Kg = Kt$ for some $t \in T$.
2. We can write any $g \in G$ as $g = a_1a_2 \cdots a_n$, where each $a_i \in X \cup X^{-1}$. Using this and induction on $n$, it is sufficent to show that, for all $t \in T$ and $a \in X \cup X^{-1}$, we have $Kta = Kt'$ for some $t' \in T$.
3. Now there are two cases, $a \in X$ and $a^{-1} \in X$. The case $a \in X$ is easy, because $ta(t.a)^{-1} \in Y \subset K$. When $a^{-1} \in X$ you need to show that $ta(t.a)^{-1} \in Y^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you dear professor. You made such a clear path for me

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen%E2%80%93Schreier_theorem , maybe this is the type of argument you're looking for (see the 'proof' subsection)?